# Functions override one another

Tags: javascript

I've got two functions, each with a variable called `s` (In this case). When I instantiate one function it's fine, but when I instantiate the other one right after, the second one overrides the first's `s`.

Code:

```
t1 = function(){
    s = 2;

    Object.defineProperty(this, "test", {
        value: function(){
            console.log(s);
        },
        configurable: false
    });
}
t2 = function(){
    s = 42;

    Object.defineProperty(this, "test", {
        value: function(){
            console.log(s);
        },
        configurable: false
    });
}

var t = new t1()
t.test(); // 2

var y = new t2();
y.test(); // 42

t.test(); // 42
```

Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp The variable 's' is automatically globally defined. Hence they are the same variable. That is why the latter overrides the former.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `s` is from the global scope. To define a variable `s` inside your function, declare it with

```
var s = 2;
```

To avoid such errors, you can add the line

```
"use strict";
```

to the beginning of your file. This way accessing an undeclared variable in the global scope will be forbidden.

Answer (score 2):

because s becomes a global variable, set var before each s.

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing `s` from somewhere outside of the functions' scopes this means that, they will share that variable because it does not get redeclared within their own scopes.

Try this:

```
t1 = function(){
    var s = 2;

    Object.defineProperty(this, "test", {
        value: function(){
            console.log(s);
        },
        configurable: false
    });
}
t2 = function(){
    var s = 42;

    Object.defineProperty(this, "test", {
        value: function(){
            console.log(s);
        },
        configurable: false
    });
}
```